# JAVA Newbie Alert: Trying to run Java class and getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, cmd, classnotfound

Java newbie. I am trying to run a java main class from cmd line and getting back `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java -cp class c:\development\eclipse\workspace\Library-Manager-Server\bin\demo\rmi\librarymanager\server\LibraryManagerServer 

-Djava.security.policy="C:\Development\Eclipse\Workspace\Library-Manager-Server\security.policy" 

-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin/ file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin/"
```

The class is definitely there in the bin (where eclipse drops it)  but for some reason (probably trivial) it cannot be found when I run the cmd line above.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT#1**: as some of you may have guessed classname is `demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer`

**EDIT#2**: OK - thanks to people suggestions I think I got the syntax right this time but I am still getting `ClassNotFoundException` but on a different class in the common package:

```
demo.rmi.librarymanager.common.Library
```

Here's the new cmd line:

```
java -cp c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer 

-Djava.security.policy="C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/security.policy" 

-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin"
```

Shall I add the `c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin` path (where `demo.rmi.librarymanager.common.Library` lives) together with `c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin` after -cp as a command line argument?

Thanks to everyone for their help and patience - I am working on an RMI application and everything was good till I was working inside eclipse using the [RMI plugin](http://www.genady.net/rmi/index.html) but now I am having a bit of an hard time as I am fairly new to java (as you cas see from my question!).

**EDIT#3**: Ok I got it working:

```
java -cp c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin;c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin 

demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer 

-Djava.security.policy="C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/security.policy" 

-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin"
```

Thanks to everyone for the shower of humbleness.

Comment: what is the 'class' argument to -cp?

Comment: without the name of the class, this is going to get votes for 'not a real question'

Comment: see below - it's probably from the java docs and is a placeholder for the classname

Comment: @bmargulies the OP is trying to get the syntax correct. We guess the classname is `demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer`

Comment: @JohnIdol I have spent many days in the past with CNFE so feel pleased that with SO it has taken less here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java commandline is:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

I think I see your problem - 'class' is not a keyword; it is the fullyQualified classname that you have to replace it with.

If your class files are in bin then the command might look like:

```
java -cp bin myClass
```

so perhaps

```
java -cp bin demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer
```

if you are in the directory of your Eclipse project.

Note that Eclipse has settings (which you can override) for where the classes are. I have found that different versions of Eclipse have different ones by default. So I have seen  `bin`,  `classes` or (as I am using maven) `target/classes`.

Comment: thanks +1 I think I got the syntax right now, getting NotFound on another class though - see edit#2.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably work:

```
java -cp c:\development\eclipse\workspace\Library-Manager-Server\bin\ demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer
```

This assumes that you want to run the class `LibraryManagerServer` in the package `demo.rmi.librarymanager.server`.

Note that if you use classes in packages (which is advisable except for short test or learning code), you have to

- Use the fully qualified name (including package) of the class to tell java.exe what class to start
- Give as classpath the *base* directory under which the directory hierarchy corresponding to the package hierarchy lives

Answer (score 1):

From your commandline I would guess:

```
java -cp c:/development/eclipse/workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin
-Djava.security.policy="C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/security.policy" 
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Server/bin/ file:/C:/Development/Eclipse/Workspace/Library-Manager-Common/bin/"
demo.rmi.librarymanager.server.LibraryManagerServer
```

Java paths use / as separators, even on widnows, the classpath should point to the root of your package hierarchy and the class to run is given in package notation relative to the classpath.